# array should be inside recursive function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, recursion

The codes are in JavaScript. My question is how do I make the `arr` array inside the function. I dont want it outside the function. The above code show `arr` array outside of the function and I dont like that. You can suggest anything, as my goal is to find all factorial of the number 36. The answer should be an array like this `[36,18,12,9,6,4,3,2,1]`.

```
var arr= []
function factor(number, divisor) {
    if(divisor >= 1) { 
        if(number % divisor == 0) {
            arr.push(divisor)
            return factor(number, divisor - 1)
        } else {
            return factor(number, divisor - 1);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log("")
console.log("factor of a number 36")
console.log(factor(36,36))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so

```
function factor(number, divisor, arr) {
  arr = arr || [];

  if (divisor >= 1) {
    if (number % divisor === 0) {
      arr.push(divisor);
      return factor(number, divisor - 1, arr);
    } else {
      return factor(number, divisor - 1, arr);
    }
  }

  return arr;
}
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/mozeca/1/edit?js,console)

Or you can do like this, in order to pass only two arguments

```
function factor(number, divisor) {
  return function _factor(number, divisor, arr) {
    arr = arr || [];

    if (divisor >= 1) {
      if (number % divisor === 0) {
        arr.push(divisor);
        return _factor(number, divisor - 1, arr);
      } else {
        return _factor(number, divisor - 1, arr);
      }
    }

    return arr;
  }(number, divisor);
}
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/mozeca/2/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

Do it like

```
 function factor(number, divisor, s)
  {
  if(number==divisor) arr = [];
  if(divisor >= 1)
  { 
  if(number % divisor == 0)
  {
    arr.push(divisor)
    return factor(number, divisor - 1)
  }
  else
  {
     return factor(number, divisor - 1);
  }
   }
  return arr;
 }
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dygk44va/)**

Comment: @void you set `arr` as global variable (I can get `arr` outside of the function `factor`) - see http://jsfiddle.net/dygk44va/1/, it is not correct..

Comment: yeah i tried to vote up but i just registered to stackoverflow today like right now with this question so i cannot vote up because "vote up require 15 reputation" lol. your answer was almost perfect so i would vote up. your code doesnt include 36 lol lol

Comment: @void because this is the same as in author version. `arr` will be as window property.

Comment: @void this is with `var arr = []` http://jsfiddle.net/dygk44va/2/ . this is without http://jsfiddle.net/dygk44va/3/. If you open this two versions you can see that you get `arr` outside of the function `factor`. It is not correct.

Comment: @john chau This is not correct answer. Have you seen my comment ?

Answer (score 0):

Declare arr inside factor function :

```
function factor(number, divisor, s) {
        var arr = []
        if (divisor >= 1) {
            if (number % divisor == 0) {
                arr.push(divisor)
                return factor(number, divisor - 1)
            } else {
                return factor(number, divisor - 1);
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

Comment: i did tried your version before i even posted the question. what happend with your version is that "var arr = [];" get reset to empty array each time the recursion is call lol. with Alexander above, the array does not get reset to empty. very clever.

Comment: I am sorry. I should have tried that before answering.